# How Zend Db Translate works with Cache

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have the following code:

```
Zend_Translate::setCache($cache);// set the cache

$translate = new Zend_Translate( 
            array('adapter' => 'DBCustom_Translate_Class', 
                 'tag'=>'translateCache'
                )
             );
$translate -> _('example')
$translate -> _('example2')
Zend_Translate::clearCache('translateCache');//please make abstraction about the fact I'm deleting the cache here.
```

The Custom_Translate_Class extends Zend_Translate_Adapter and implements the abstract functions(_loadTranslationData and toString)

_loadTranslationData is never called, why ?
I want to be able to check if a token for a translation exists in db if not I wanna create it, so I need to be able to actually do something in this class

What is the best practice to use cache along with custom  db translation class

Answer (score 0):

I found out that calling addTranslation method $translate->addTranslation('Custom_Class_Adapter'); will make a call to _loadTranslationData

Answer (score 0):

Does your Custom_Translate_Class calls parent constructor in it's own, like this ? :

```
public function __construct($data, $locale = null, array $options = array())
{
    parent::__construct($data, $locale, $options);
}
```

And by the way, you should rename it to Custom_Translate_Adapter, to respect the naming conventions (but it shouldn't affect the way it works).